# Deploy war file without restarting Tomcat 7 using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, ant

I'm using Jenkins and Ant for deploying my war file from one server to other server machines. The first time, it successfully deployed the war file to the corresponding tomcat server and it worked fine. But the second time and afterwards, the war file is deleted and Tomcat is not deleting the corresponding "unwar" folder because Tomcat is currently running. So I couldn't deploy a war file.

I also tried adding `reloadable="true"` to the `conf\context` file. However, it shows the following error:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\sample]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

How can I resolve this issue? I want to deploy a war file to tomcat without stopping Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to undeploy your application using the Tomcat manager and a wget command?

```
wget --http-user=tomcat --http-password=tomcat "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/SomeWar" -O -
```

Comment: If want to safely undeploy your app, I think the wget solution is the best.